# What is the default print method of a class when called in a console?

Tags: python

In a Python interactive console (IDLE, IPython, etc), if I enter a variable name by itself, I will get back the equivalent of printing that variable.

```
In [1]: foo = {'a':1, 'b':2}
In [2]: foo
Out [2]: {'a':1, 'b':2}
In [3]: print(foo)
Out [3]: {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

I'd like to incorporate this functionality into a container class, like:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
    def __mysteryfunction__(self)
        print(self.bar)
```

I'd like the class to print as before, but instead I get:

```
In [1]: foo = Foo({'a':1, 'b':2})
In [2]: foo
Out [2]: <__main__.foo at 0x1835c093128>
```

I've searched for nearly every permutation I can think of for what this might be called, and haven't found the same question. Is this a class method like I'm hoping, or something built into the console interpreter? If the latter, can it be modified?

Comment: Use the magic methods `__str__` and `__repr__` for `print` and REPL respectively.

Comment: I should also note I'm aware of the __call__ function, but wonder if there's a way to just use `foo` instead of `foo()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `print x`, `x.__str__` is called.
For output in a REPL when an object is returned, `x.__repr__` is called.

Read about [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) functions.

Comment: Perfect, __repr__ is what I was looking for. Added a complete answer to the end of the question based on yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the `__str__` method of a class.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> `object.__str__(self)`
>
> Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __str__(self):
        return 'My name is foo and my bar is ' + self.bar

foobar = Foo('high')

print(foobar)  # My name is foo and my bar is high
```